# Как задать img src (background-size:cover)

Tags: html, css

как растянуть `img src` как `cover` без `background-image` в CSS

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно использовать свойство `object-fit`

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}
img{
   object-fit: cover;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg">
    </body>
</html>
```

Вот как свойство `object-fit:cover` описывает [документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit#values):

> Размер замененного содержимого изменяется таким образом, чтобы
> сохранить его соотношение сторон при заполнении всего поля содержимого
> элемента. Если соотношение сторон объекта не соответствует соотношению
> сторон его блока, то объект будет обрезан по размеру.